# How to do multiply select using PDO

Tags: php, sql, database, pdo

i'm working on a project, where i have a database where is all the information about an artist, his name, his album etc...

I'm displaying card with a foreach, and then i want to open a modal, with all the information about this artist.
In this modal i'm showing all the other album he did.

But i'm new using PDO and i'm not sure to understand how it's really working. I want to pick all album of the artist.

```html
<?php 
$artistStatement = $mysqlConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM album');


$artistStatement->execute();
$artists = $artistStatement->fetchAll();



?>

<?php foreach ($artists as $artist) {
?>
   
        <div class="music-card" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#<?=$artist['Artiste'].'_'.$artist['Album']?>">
          <a href="#" ><img src="img/<?=$artist['Artiste'].'_'.$artist['Album'] . '.jpg'?>" alt=""></a>
          <p><?=$album['Artiste']</p>
          <p><?=$album['Album']?></p>
        </div>

        <div class="modal fade" id="<?=$artist['Artiste'].'_'.$artist['Album']?>" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
              </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                                  
                      <div class="card-left">
                        <div class="header-card">
                        
                         <div class="proposition">
                  
                          <p class="ff">Album de <?=$artist['Artiste'] </p>
      
                        <div class="d-flex flex-row">
                          <div class="d-flex flex-column">
                          <a href="#"><img class="img-fluid "src="img/<? "Here is where i need help .>.jpg'?>" alt=""></a>
                          <div class="text-propo d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
                            <p><?=$artist['album']r</p>
                            <p>2019</p>
                            
                     </div>
                   </div>
                </div>  
             </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: and where is the form that sends the artist name id ...

Comment: How can i open a modal if i submit with a form?

Comment: only with ajax, better make a form where you select the artist and then you can use AJAX to get the information for that artist or use your code with $POST or $GET to catch the form slection